# how do I restrict ipad app to ios6 only?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

Ive developed an app which I want to upload to the AppStore, but the code contains various methods which can only be used in IOS6. Is it just simply a case of setting the SDK to 6 before uploading, or is there more to it than that? The last thing I want is for people to download it on an iPad running IOS5 and the app crashing on them because it doesnt support the operating system!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to adjust your deployment target to the iOS you want to support, if it is iOS 6, just set it to iOS 6.0.